# Slick .js cannot add null error

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

After destroying the slick and reinitializing the slick gives the following error:

> error cannot read property add of null

Here is my code:

```
$('#id').slick('unslick')

$('#id').slick()
```

Comment: [What is the X Y Problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/102937)

Comment: I tried it reinitializing the slick after loading the slider and gave a certain time out even then I am getting the same issue I.e., cannot read property add of null for reinitializing the slick

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to add this? It worked for me, it seams for some reason that slick is fired multiple times.

```
$("#").not('.slick-initialized').slick()
```